# Adding an overlay to the camera view rather than the map view

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to add a 'target' which would be represented as a circle which must always remain at the center of the current map view. Looking through the API I see a lot about adding Markers, Shapes, Ground overlays and Tile overlays but none seem to be adaptable to my needs.

Basically they are all used to draw elements 'on the map' at specified locations. What I need is some sort of overlay for the actual camera view. A good example would be when looking through the lens of the camera where a circle denotes the center of the frame.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a RelativeLayout, which contains the MapFragment plus an additional custom view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<mypackage.MyCustomView
    android:id="@+id/mapOverlay" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@android:color/transparent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Whatever you draw into the custom view, e.g. a circle in the center, is drawn on top of the map, and will stay there, independent of the maps movement.

If you want to adapt the shape to the zoom, tilt, etc. you need to listen to camera changes and adapt the drawing accordingly. Unfortunately the CameraChangeListener is only called, after the change is finished. So you can not immediately follow the zoom or tilt gesture with your drawing.